# passing semicolon in URL as a paramater

Tags: java, url, jsonp

I have HTML string like as bellow

```
<span style="font-weight:bold; color:red;"> Hello </span>
```

I want to pass it as JSONP request so server can parse it easily. like

```
../save/question?id=5&code="<span style="font-weight:bold; color:red;"> Hello </span>"&callback=123213
```

but server cant parse properly because of semicolon in string. Any solution for this so When i retrive data  from server i got complete HTML string with styling.?

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon and colon are both reserved characters in URLs, and so must be escaped.

Construct your query string and then pass it through javascript [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before adding it to your request.

Comment: @MayankPandya it depends on your server side code, but probably not. If you're using e.g. [`ServletRequest.getRequestURI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI()) then you **will** need to decode the query string, if you use `ServletRequest.getParameter`, you'll get _decoded_ parameter values.